# flatten (e.g. sum) a 3d array to a matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I would like to know how to turn a 3d array into a matrix, by e.g. summing, averaging, or taking the maximum or minimum over the 3rd dimension.

This sounds like something that would have already been asked, I did look around quite a bit but couldn't find exactly this.

A [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135415/efficiently-compute-the-row-sums-of-a-3d-array-in-r) would be:

```
> a3 <- array(c(1:9, 1:9), c(3,3,2))
> a3
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way appears to be using `apply()`.

```
> apply(a3, 1:2, sum)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8   14
[2,]    4   10   16
[3,]    6   12   18
```

Where `1:2` are passed to the `MARGIN` argument and represent the dimensions of the input object (`X`) to be preserved.

**Note that this also applies to higher dimensional arrays.**

For `mean()` this would of course be:

```
> apply(a3, 1:2, mean)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

and similarly you can use `min()`, `max()`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rowSums` for this (or `rowMeans` for the average), setting the appropriate `dims`

```
# sum
rowSums(a3, dims = 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    8   14
# [2,]    4   10   16
# [3,]    6   12   18

# average
rowMeans(a3, dims = 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, these are very handy, I take it from the name of the argument that this can even be applied to e.g. dimensions 3 & 4 of an array?

Comment: @bquast ; yes that's right (try `ar = array(1:16, dim = c(2,2,2,2)) ; apply(ar, 1:3, sum) ; rowSums(ar, dims = 3)`). It is also faster, especially if you are having to repeat a computation many times, but the `MARGIN` argument of your `apply` solution is more versatile and I find it easier to remember